# Automated Test for WPF, Localization, WinFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, localization, automated-tests

Our team is attempting to implement automated test for several large applications -- some of them old, and only partially updated to newer technology.

Specifically, we have some WPF applications that include WinFormsHost elements.  That seems to throw some test suites (eg Telerik TestStudio) for a loop.

We also need to test our apps in several languages using localization -- including unicode languages like Chinese, which are no-can-do for other test suites (eg SmartBear TestComplete).

We're working with both of the above vendors to find some way to work around their limitations; but I'm not optimistic that they're going to come up with solutions (and our company isn't a big enough fish for them to do anything special for us).  So I'm hoping perhaps someone has an idea for a product that might meet our needs.  Record/Playback is nice, but a powerful scripting language is probably more valuable to us.

Thanks for any suggestions anyone can make.